# Javascript to click button, choose options?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a JavaScript that chooses an option from a drop down, clicks that options and then clicks another button to add this option to cart, how would I create this in a JavaScript code?

Here's what I've tried:

```
browser.getelementbyid("id").invokemember("click");
```

Comment: What you're looking for is called "cascaded dropdown". Give it a go on google. The code you provided doesn't do anything by its own and you really should have an understanding about the logic before giving it a go yourself.

Comment: Thank you man.. Can I get your email I am trying to create something.. I would appreciate your expertise!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I formatting your code

Comment: Thanks for the welcome! Can you help me create a script I am trying to do? Can we email or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery, it helps alot I find.

```
$('#YourElement').click()
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.. any good video tutorials on this?

Comment: Video tutorials on jQuery?

Comment: Yes to help something like my question.

Comment: @KingPey try looking up cascading dropbox on google or youtube. You could also look up jQuery tutorials.

Comment: Rick or Wyatt can I also have your emails I need help with creating something and would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is:

- when something change in a drop down field
- you want to trigger a click on another element

Because you want to listen to the change event here's a short example and an area to play with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/je5Lgne5/

```
$('#products').change(function() {
  var selectedOption = $(this).val();
  $('#cart').append($('<li />').html(selectedOption));
});
```

Comment: Hey Filype can I have your email I need help with creating something I would really appreciate it!